# Clearing out 'finished' service history in DC/OS

Tags: user-interface, marathon, dcos

I am currently setting up a POC network of dockerised services using DC/OS. As this is a POC, I have had to make many revisions to the containers in order to get things working.

Consequently, when drilling into some services using the DC/OS (v1.8.7) web UI, I can see hundreds of old tasks - the vast majority of which have a status of 'finished'.

I realise that I can filter out and just see the 'active' containers by clicking on the appropriate tab, but this is not what I am after because I would like to be able to see when a container is staging, and also - all the history for the finished tasks is worthless to me.

**How do I purge DC/OS of these finished tasks, as they are clogging up the UI?**

Is there a CLI command for this, or do I have to clear out stuff on the master nodes... or is there an handy plug-in that will manage this for me? I've been looking around both on the web and the master nodes, but can't work out what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DC/OS 1.8.x there is no UI or CLI method to influence garbage collection. You can however, with a custom install, influence some parameter, such as `gc_delay` (default value: 2 days in DC/OS) and others are using the [Mesos defaults](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/), like `gc_disk_headroom` (which is unchanged set to `0.1`, which means, Mesos targets to have 10% of the assigned disk as free space).

For parameters you can change at install time see the [Install Configuration Parameters](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/installing/custom/configuration-parameters/#-a-name-gc-delay-a-gc_delay) docs for more details.